# Function with generics that returns class with generics in .d.ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I try to modify code, that works in regular usage, to use with declarations generation (or manually write declarations). The code is like this:

```
function createClass<T>( data: T )
{
    abstract class Internal<T2>
    {
        public constructor( arg: T2 )
        {
            console.log( data, arg );
        }

        protected abstract method( arg: T ): void;
    }

    return Internal;
}
```

The problem is that i should to specify type of function result, but I don't know how to do this — I tried different options and none worked.

**Added:**

This small example may not be completely clear, so I add the original code with which the problem occurred:

Original code, that I'm trying to turn into a package: https://gist.github.com/Avol-V/1af4748f4b0774a999311c92b6dc1631

Code of `small-redux` you can find there: https://github.com/m18ru/small-redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts

Code of `preact` you can find there: https://github.com/developit/preact/blob/master/src/preact.d.ts

The problem is that I don't want to specify the TState type to every usage of created class — it can't be changed on created class so it's incorrect.

**Added:**

So, I didn’t find any solution to not specify `T` explicitly in the generic of the created class (additionally to the `T2` — `class Internal<TInternal, T2>`). My result code looks like: https://github.com/m18ru/preact-small-redux/blob/85c143e851b92c44861dc976ce6ef89bcda2c884/src/index.ts

If you just want to write a function that returns class with generic, you can do this as @baryo suggests (with some cleanup):

```
declare abstract class AbstractInternal<T>
{
    public abstract method( arg: T ): void;
}

function createClass(): typeof AbstractInternal
{
    abstract class Internal<T> implements AbstractInternal<T>
    {
        public abstract method( arg: T ): void;
    }

    return Internal;
}

const A = createClass();

class B extends A<string>
{
    public method( arg: string ): string
    {
        return 'Hello ' + arg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything you create inside the function is scoped to it, including types. So you need to at least define types out of it. Maybe the following will help you:

```
interface IInternal<T> {
    method(arg: T): void;
}

type InternalCtor<T> = new (param: T) => IInternal<T>;

function createClass<T>(data: T): InternalCtor<T>
{
    abstract class Internal<T> implements IInternal<T>
    {
        public constructor( arg: T )
        {
            console.log( data, arg );
        }

        public abstract method( arg: T ): void;
    }

    return Internal as InternalCtor<T>;
}

class A extends createClass<number>(1) {
    public method() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

const z = new A(2);  // 1 2
```

edit:
you mentioned you're interested that a generic method will return a generic class - it becomes a bit tricky with typings but we can just let Typescript itself infer everything we need.

```
function createClass<T>(data: T)
{
    // directly return a new class with a different generic type.
    //  notice that you can't return an abstract class.
    return class Internal<U>
    {
        public constructor( arg: U )
        {
            console.log( data, arg );
        }

        public method(arg: T): void { console.log(arg); }
    }
}



// first generic type (number) is for the function, then the second generic type (string) is for the returned class.
class A extends createClass<number>(1)<string> {

}

const z = new A('zzz');   // 1 zzz
z.method(2); // 2
```

edit 2:
it's a bit different from what you're looking but i think a better practice will be the following (similar to what @Diullei suggested):

```
abstract class AbstractInternal<T> {
    public abstract method(arg: T): void;
}

type InternalCtor<T> = new (param: T) => AbstractInternal<T>;

function createClass<T, U>(data: T): InternalCtor<U> {
    abstract class Internal<U> implements AbstractInternal<U>
    {
        public constructor(arg: T) {
            console.log(data, arg);
        }

        public abstract method(arg: U): void;
    }

    return Internal as any as InternalCtor<U>;
}

class A extends createClass<number, string>(1) {
    public method(arg: string) { // now I need to implement this to avoid a compilation error
        console.log(`hello ${arg}`);
    }
}

const z = new A('arg'); // 1 "arg""
z.method('arg2'); // "hello arg2""
```

Comment: Good job! the unique thing I think you need to change is your `IInternal<T>` interface. It needs to be an abstract class with the abstract `method( arg: T ): void` function to enforce the class `A` to implement this method.

Comment: thanks! but then it won't have access to the scoped `data` parameter of the function.

Comment: yes, it will. Take a look https://gist.github.com/Diullei/21ad4fe56cd51e9330c998995d17a23e

Comment: Thanks, folks. Maybe I'm not fully understand your example, but there is only one generic type, and in my example internal class has its own generic type.
To be clear, I add original code to my question — can you please look at it?

Comment: Thanks, @baryo, but in your example `method` has type `U`, but it should be `T`. Looks like impossible, but I want to strictly specify type of the method argument to generic type of the creating function.

Comment: modified and added another suggestion